# PHP Split PayPal Charge

Tags: php, paypal

Is there a way I can split a paypal charge with PHP? Im looking for 90% going to one account and 10% going to another account, but when the person is charged it should look like it is just going to the 10% account. I'd like the person to be charged using IPN. Anyway to do this with PHP?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method should be adaptable to your challenge:

https://www.x.com/thread/40474

Answer (score 0):

No you'll just have to deal with splitting the funds yourself later on.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you're trying to scam the user/person by only showing the 10% charge, why would you do this? If you're making two PayPal transactions why not charge the 100% and then send 10% of that to another account? You are still being charged for two transactions and the user/person gets to see one transaction

Comment: he's not trying to show the 10% amount, just the 10% account.  Regardless, it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

What he want is that when someone pays 100$ it says 100$ sent to yourshop.com, but actually only 10$ is sent to yourshop.com and 90$ is sent to yourreseller.com. It doesn't seem like a scam but more like a percentage seller, but it's still not possible...